# Merge 2 MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables with the following structure:

```
Custom Pricing List
+------------+--------------+------------ +
| stock_code | stored_price | pricing_ref | 
+------------+--------------+------------ +

Generic Pricing List
+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| stock_code | last_purchase_price | sales_price  | description | qty_in_stock |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

What I would like to return is the following:

```
+------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| stock_code | last_purchase_price | sales_price  | description | qty_in_stock |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Currently I am only querying the last table, using the following MySQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column LIKE '%$term%' $or LIMIT 0,10
```

However I'd like to merge the 2 and still have the ability to do a wildcard search on the `stock_code` column.

All results MUST return the `description` and `qty_in_stock`. The `sales_price` in the result will be either `stored_price` from the `Custom Pricing Table` or `sales_price` from the `Generic Pricing Table` however `stored_price` takes precedence over `sales_price` from the `Generic Pricing Table`.

I understand I need to do a UNION query, however I am unsure how I could write it.

#### EDIT

Using the statement:

```
SELECT stock.*, price.*
    FROM stock
    LEFT INNER JOIN price 
        ON stock.stock_code = price.stock_code
    WHERE stock.stock_code LIKE '%123%'
    LIMIT 0,10
```

I now receive the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN price 
        ON stock.stock_code = price.stock_code
    WHERE stock.stoc' at line 3
```

Comment: is `stock_code` field unique ?

Comment: @Viral ... Yes the `stock_code` field is unique to each table. However it will exist in each table. ie `stock_code: 1234` will be in both the custom and generic tables.

Comment: `stored_price` is numeric or varchar ?

Comment: `stored_price` is type `double`. The data has been extracted from a Sage v50 database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can join both the tables. Try this:

```
SELECT 
generic.stock_code, 
generic.last_purchase_price, 
IFNULL(custom.stored_price, generic.sales_price) AS actual_price, 
generic.description, 
generic.qty_in_stock 
FROM 
Generic_Pricing_List generic
JOIN Custom_Pricing_List custom
on custom.stock_code = generic.stock_code
WHERE $column LIKE '%$term%' $or LIMIT 0,10;
```

If stored_price is not null and is defined, it will be picked up. Otherwise, sales_price will be picked up.

Comment: I made a slight adjustment to your code, changing the line `IFNULL(custom.stored_price, generic.sales_price),` to `IFNULL(custom.stored_price, generic.sales_price) AS actual_price,` and it is working perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.field1, t2.field2 
FROM $table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN $table2 AS t2 ON (t1.stock_code = t2.stock_code) 
WHERE t1.$column LIKE '%$term%' $or 
LIMIT 0,10
```

simply use `JOIN`

Comment: The trouble with this is, although it sort of merges the tables... It creates 2 `stock_code` columns. It also only matches on rows where the stock_code from `t1` matches `t2`. I'd like it to carry on returning results from `t1` even if there is no match.

Comment: just use LEFT JOIN :)

Answer (score 0):

`Left Inner Join` will get you all rows from `Generic_Pricing_List` and matching rows from `Custom_Pricing_List`.

```
SELECT Generic_Pricing_List.*, Custom_Pricing_List.stored_price, Custom_Pricing_List.pricing_ref
FROM Generic_Pricing_List
LEFT INNER JOIN Custom_Pricing_List
    ON Generic_Pricing_List.stock_code = Custom_Pricing_List.stock_code
WHERE Generic_Pricing_List.Search_Column LIKE '%Term%'
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Please see my updated question, I am now receiving a violation error

Comment: I have noticed a huge performance hit since using a LEFT JOIN. A transaction that used to take <1 second now takes 3-4 seconds to complete. Is there any way I could speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.*
FROM Generic_Pricing_List g
LEFT JOIN Custom_Pricing_List c
    ON g.stock_code = c.stock_code
WHERE g.Search_Column LIKE '%Term%'
LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union, but it's not required.  The union, however, might be more efficient with larger data sets because "if"s can be expensive.  Quick and dirty:

```
SELECT gpl.stock_code, last_purchase_price, if(stored_price is null, sales_price, stored_price) as sales_price, description, qty_in_stock
FROM Generic_Pricing_List gpl
LEFT JOIN Custom_Pricing_List cpl
    ON gpl.stock_code = cpl.stock_code
    AND cpl.stored_price != ''
    AND cpl.stored_price IS NOT NULL
WHERE $column LIKE '%$term%' $or
LIMIT 0,10
```

Using a union:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT gpl.stock_code, last_purchase_price, stored_price as sales_price, description, qty_in_stock
FROM Generic_Pricing_List gpl
JOIN Custom_Pricing_List cpl
    ON gpl.stock_code = cpl.stock_code
    AND cpl.stored_price != ''
    AND cpl.stored_price IS NOT NULL
WHERE $column LIKE '%$term%' $or
UNION
SELECT gpl.stock_code, last_purchase_price, sales_price, description, qty_in_stock
FROM Generic_Pricing_List gpl
WHERE $column LIKE '%$term%' $or) foo
GROUP BY foo.stock_code
LIMIT 0,10
```

Be careful of the "or" statement being injected, as it might cause problems with the results.